# Failed to load jvm.dll (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

So I want to setup Eclipse on my VPS. But, I keep getting this error.
I've tried Google, and possible tried every "fix" but still nothing.
I've tried the most common, with downloading the jre7 but still no luck.

Heres a picture of it: http://gyazo.com/30f261a44ff45d9ae2072d1194a9161e

And also, my ini file: http://pastebin.com/eaTXABVy

If someone could help me with this, I would be grateful! And sorry for bad English.

Comment: You are using a 32 bit JRE with 64 bit Eclipse. They must both be 32 bit or 64 bit.